# How to run .scesim files in Drools ? Is it even possible to run in Drools?

Tags: java, spring-boot, drools, dmn

I have created Drools-springboot application having dmn model. I have created .scesim file of that particular dmn file and want to test it with in Visual Studio code. How I can achieve this ?
I tried running with the Kogito, it runs fine but I am not sure hhow .scesim files are executed with drools.

Answer (score 0):

For running scesim file. is enough to:

- have 'KogitoScenarioJunitActivatorTest' file in your project, see [1] for example
- and have dependency for a 'kogito-scenario-simulation' artifact [2]

[1]
https://github.com/kiegroup/kogito-examples/blob/stable/dmn-quarkus-example/src/test/java/testscenario/KogitoScenarioJunitActivatorTest.java

[2]
https://github.com/kiegroup/kogito-examples/blob/stable/dmn-quarkus-example/pom.xml